# Web apps and deep links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, branch.io

I'm trying to incorporate deep links/universal links for my music app so when I send out emails to people regarding new songs/albums, they will either be directed to details page or the login/signup page (with the song/album info displayed).

[branch.io](https://branch.io) looks good but I'm having a tough time understanding how my app would handle the appropriate redirects for a single-page app. When a user clicks on a generated link, how should my app request for more data based on that user's link so I can render the correct page/view?

Comment: Use react-router. It's pretty easy to define your routes there with parameters and everything.

Comment: If I want to take advantage of the features of branch.io, such as tracking the channel the user is coming from and displaying the correct view, at what part of my app should I fetch/consume that data before telling react-router where to go?

Answer (score 0):

The flow is pretty simple. Create a Branch link with all the parameters you want to pass -> you click on the link -> Redirect to your the web app -> Initialise Branch Web SDK -> Callback is received with all the parameters -> Use these parameters to navigate to whatever page you want in your app and/or use these parameters to customise your user experience.

You can read more about it here:
https://docs.branch.io/web/integrate/#read-deep-link
https://docs.branch.io/deep-linking/routing/#branch-added-parameters

In case you still have doubt feel free to reach out to our super helpful support team at support@branch.io

Comment: I'm able to receive the link parameters in my `index.html` and I'm saving that data to `window._branch_`. But in my `App.js` `componentDidMount`, `window._branch_` is undefined. When a user opens a link, I want to save the link parameters to redux and then use react-router to redirect. What is the flow for that scenario?

Comment: Should I contact support for technical questions or can we continue to discuss here?

Comment: How can I access the `bracnh.init` data in my React components?

Comment: We would need to see your code and debug to find out what's going wrong, I would recommend you to reach out to support with all the details and code snippet